# How do you set a border in excel up to a certain column

Tags: python, excel, dataframe

I am writing a dataframe to excel and trying to add borders. At the moment, I have figured out how to add the borders to the worksheet using

```
bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True, 'border': True})
```

```
worksheet.set_row(1, cell_format=bold)
```

but this extends the border past the last column of the dataframe. Is there a way to stop the borders at the last column of my dataframe?

Thanks

Comment: What package are you using to write the excel file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's the one you're using, but this can be done with the package `openpyxl`.

First we can create a test dataframe:

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles import Border, Side
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
import pandas

headers = ["column1", "column2", "column3"]
records = [{k: 0 for k in headers} for _ in range(25)]
df = pandas.DataFrame.from_records(records)
```

Now we create a workbook object and put the dataframe in it:

```
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active
for row in dataframe_to_rows(df, index=False, header=True):
    ws.append(row)
```

Next I define a thin border which will be used around the whole dataset

```
thin_border = Side(border_style="thin", color='FF000000')
```

Now I construct the borders required for each individual cell. You didn't specify how you would like to border the data so I assumed a border around the outside of the entire frame. Since we know the number of columns and rows we can iterate through the cells and construct the parameters for the `Border` constructor that are appropriate for each cell in the sheet.

```
for i in range(1, len(df) + 2):  # Excel indexes at 1 and header row is extra
    for j in range(1, len(headers) + 1):
        sides = {"top": Side(), "bottom": Side(), "left": Side(), "right": Side()}
        if j == 1:  # Left Most Column:
            sides["left"] = thin_border

        if i == 1:  # Top Row
            sides["top"] = thin_border

        if j == len(headers):  # Right Most Column
            sides["right"] = thin_border

        if i == len(df) + 1:  # Bottom Row
            sides["bottom"] = thin_border

        ws.cell(i, j).border = Border(**sides)  # Apply sides to current cell

wb.save("output.xlsx")
```

Note that I had to use `Border(**sides)` since the `Side` objects are immutable in the package. I'm not sure if there's a more efficient way to do this, since I don't have a lot of experience with the package, but this gets it done.

It should be straightforward from here to apply bordering however you see fit.